# How to eliminate space between lines when highlighting?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a custom text editor and I am trying to eliminate spaces between lines when selected by highlighting as shown below. I'm not sure how I can remedy this without fundamentally changing the structure of the HTML, which I cannot do. Any advice is greatly appreciate.

**Edit:** I do not want to simply decrease line height. I rather want to extend the amount of vertical space the highlighting takes up.

[image]

```css
p {
  display: block;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 19.5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-indent: -3px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 498.5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only
}

span {
  display: inline;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 19.5px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-indent: -3px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only
}
```

```html
<p data-key="838">
  <span data-key="837">
    <span data-offset-key="837-0">
    Line of text one
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
<p data-key="842">
  <span data-key="841">
    <span data-offset-key="841-0">
    Line of text two
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
<p data-key="844">
  <span data-key="843">
    <span data-offset-key="843-0">
    Line of text three
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a45Mm/), because it doesn't look nice

Comment: just reduce line-height

Comment: I want the items spaced as they are. I just want highlighting to extend vertically. I have edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: CSS Tricks has a nice post about this https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

Comment: Lars, perhaps my question was unclear and I should have used numerals instead of writing out numbers. My concern isn't the differences in horizontal width, but rather the spaces between the vertical lines. Your link does not seem to cover that, right? My question was a bit unclear I see now.

Comment: I got your question wrong, sorry